# Recording vr motion video

Tags: virtual-reality, aframe

I want to record a vr motion video of my house using aframe so that I can show the demo view of the the house.What are the js files need to be included?How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to record 360º video — if so, a 360º camera is the place to start. See: http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-360-degree-camera/

You may want to test things out on your device (Gear VR, Cardboard, Vive, whatever) before investing in a camera. Video playback in A-Frame may have some issues on mobile devices particularly.

Example: https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/videosphere/

Comment: Can I do it without using a 360 camera, I mean by normal mobile camera (are there any applications for the specific purpose), or else we need to build a model of the house objects?

Comment: You could create a series of 360º photos on a normal phone, using something like the Cardboard Camera app. I think that's the best that is possible right now, on a normal mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

hi kumar yes you use without using 360 camera by using normal mobile phone but to place that video you have to use latest version of unity that support not only 360 video format but also plane so where you can put that video as an medium.
or if you are using unity 4.6 to unity 5.3 then use have to use some packages like easy video texture in this package you have different options for placing video 
https://github.com/maazirfan/Easy-Movie-Texture-for-Unity 
and use where ever you want vr/gear vr / htc vive .